# Relation between type safety and practicality of garbage collection

Tags: garbage-collection

What are the feature of C Programming language that break the type-safety and prohibits practical garbage collection from being added to the language? Explain.
Firstly, I don't understand the relationship between type-safety and garbage collection. I'd appreciate if someone can help me with that.

Comment: How would the garbage collector know the difference between a pointer to an object and a random bit of memory that just happens to hold the same value?

Comment: This is the point exactly! So the solution is to use conservative collection!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **can** do garbage collection in C. It is called [conservative garbage collection](http://www.hpl.hp.com/personal/Hans_Boehm/gc/). The trick is to treat any data that looks like a pointer as if it were in fact a pointer, and not reclaim any memory that is reachable through it. There are two problems: first, you cannot move data around (i.e., compaction), because of the uncertainty of whether something that looks like a pointer is in fact a pointer (so updating it to point to a new location could result in data corruption).

The type-safety problem is that it is possible for a C programmer to store a pointer to an int, perform math on it, and then restore the pointer (as in: `ptrdiff_t d = (ptrdiff_t) ptr; ptr = NULL; d += 42; /* GC here would be bad */ d -= 42;`) This pointer hiding could lead a conservative garbage collector to prematurely reclaim memory that was only reachable through that pointer.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. First, it was not clear for me since I didn't remember the type casting.

Comment: Actually, the situation is even worse.  A 100% legitimate C program could repeatedly allocate and populate a big chunk of memory, store a pointer to it in a union with `unsigned char[sizeof(void*)]`, output the contents of that array (probably in hex) to the console, and overwrite all trace of that pointer.  It could then, after having done that a bunch of times, accept a sequence of hex digits, use the aforementioned union to convert them back into a pointer, and show the contents of the memory identified thereby.  Since the C standard requires that pointers remain valid as long as...

Comment: ...data sufficient to reconstitute the underlying `char[]` is stored *anywhere* and doesn't even require it to be *inside the computer*, it would in many cases be impossible for a C implementation to determine whether any particular pointer still exists (it might be able to make such determination for pointers that have never been aliased to `unsigned char`, but that would preclude GC for any pointer that's ever been exposed to `memcpy`).

Answer (score -1):

There is no relation between type safety and garbage collection whatsoever. For example, there is a language called Ada (not much popular these days though) which is very type safe, but doesn't feature garbage collector. At the same time Javascript is a dynamic language (i.e. no type safety at all) but has garbage collector in most implementations.